# Node child_process: Nested Batch Files

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, batch-file, child-process

I am trying to execute a batch script via node's `spawn()` like what is shown below:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const script = require.resolve('./script_1.bat');
const bat = spawn(script);

/* program runs properly (for the most part) */
bat.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log('stdErr: ' + data);
});

bat.on('exit', (code) => {
    console.log('Child exited with code' + code);
});
```

The problem is that `script_1.bat` has a `call` command to `script_2.bat` in the same directory:

```
`call script_2.bat`
```

When I execute `script_1.bat` in the command line, it works fine. However, when I run `script_1.bat` from node, I see this in the console:

```
stdErr: 'script_2.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I have done my best to dig through the node child process documentation, but I could not find an explination for why this would happen. Is there a way to pass nested batch files into the `spawn()` method some how?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm not used to java, but the error message you get tells you that cmd can't find the file **script_2.bat**. Try placing a **cd & pause** command before the call to see if **script_1.bat** is spawned from the same path as **script_2.bat** is.

Comment: @elizooilogico it was an issue with the file path. I updated `script_1.bat` to reference the absolute path of `script_2.bat` and it worked in node. If you can put that into an answer I will accept

Comment: seem to be an issue where java code start with its own path, so not referencing an explicit path, makes default's java path be the starting point for calles. glad to know you solved it, and thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Change this in the 1st batch:

```
call ./script_2.bat
```